# PHP extension mcrypt is not enabled on server

Tags: php, wordpress, mcrypt

I'm modifying a plugin in wordpress. The plugin is "RegistrationMagic", when I inhaled it and went to the screen it appeared the following message "PHP extension mcrypt is not enabled on server".

I tried to follow the hint of that question "https://askubuntu.com/questions/460837/mcrypt-extension-is-missing-in-14-04-server-for-mysql"

But when I get to that part:

```
Sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
Sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

Can not find conf.d file

Someone can help me: I already tried to reinstall php5 but it did not work either.

**EDIT**

When I do a locate in myscript.so it returns this below:

```
$locate mcrypt.so

/usr/lib/libmcrypt.so.4
/usr/lib/libmcrypt.so.4.4.8
/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so
```

Comment: What about php_info? are mcrypt enabled?

Comment: Sorry for your doubt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP doesn't compile mcrypt by default.  you first have to have mcrypt installed

You need to compile PHP with the `--with-mcrypt[=DIR]` parameter to enable this extension. `DIR` is the mcrypt install directory. Make sure you compile `libmcrypt` with the option `--disable-posix-threads`

an example for enabling it on ubuntu, in terminal run the following:

```
apt-get install php5-mcrypt
mv -i /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/
php5enmod mcrypt
service apache2 restart
```

here is an article on the php5enmod command: https://lornajane.net/posts/2012/managing-php-5-4-extensions-on-ubuntu

to Fix a missing mcrypt ini:

```
sudo updatedb 
locate mcrypt.ini
```

Should show it located at `/etc/php5/mods-available`

```
locate mcrypt.so
```

Edit `mcrypt.ini` and change extension to match the path to `mcrypt.so`, example:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so
```

Now this:

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

Verify that new files exists here (they should be auto created from the issue above)

```
ls -al /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
ls -al /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

Otherwise do the following

Create symbol links now

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Restart php5 or php5-fpm

```
sudo service php5 restart
```

Comment: mv: cannot stat '/etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini': No such file or directory

Comment: the above commands are only for ubuntu (well and other aptitude distros)

Comment: if you're on ubuntu are you on php5 and is the php5-mcrypt package installed?

Comment: Yes the php5 and myscript seems to be installed, the problem is with this file, which is not where it should be.

Comment: @MarciusLeandro added additional infor for locating the needed files

Comment: This is exactly what is in my question, the command that tries to create the symbol is not right because it does not find conf.d.

Comment: if you don't have a conf.d `folder` then you should be looking in `mods-available`  the first three commands are so you know where the extension is

Comment: as I said, run `locate mcrypt.ini`

Comment: then `locate mcrypt.so`

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1078963/php-5-6-20-etc-php5-conf-d-directory-missing

Answer (score 1):

Check if mcrypt is enabled or not

`php -i | grep mcrypt`

Now if it displays you something related to `myrypt` and its version mean mcrypt is already enabled. just restart your apache server and you're good to go.

and i think that's your only issue, rest you know already.

In case if it's not installed

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
OR
using PECL
sudo pecl install mcrypt
```

Comment: When I gave the command it does not show anything in the return of the grep, and when intalo it seems that already it is installed, My problem is with the conf.d

Comment: well then either mcrypt is not installed or it is not enabled.

Comment: since you already have the console access, just run sudo pecl install mcrypt if you use pecl for installation, or sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

Comment: So I believe that myscript is not enabled, how do I enable it? Because install it already tried and nothing changes, this file does not appear and the message that it is not enabled continues.

Comment: just try locate mcrypt.so and tell if it tells you something or not